# Website for e-filing income tax india

Tags: income-tax, india

Is there any recommended website for filing ITR in India except for government's website ?

Comment: Any issues with the Government website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tax-filing portals such as:

- [Taxspanner.com](http://www.taxspanner.com/)
- [Taxsmile.com](http://taxspanner.com/)
- [hrblock](http://www.hrblock.in/)

Read this [article](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/How-to-e-file-your-income-tax-returns/articleshow/9180046.cms) for a comparison among the above 2.

Comment: can they be trusted? :)

Comment: As far as i know, they are pretty trust-worthy. But as with any financial site, you should be a little cautious.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand.

Comment: What do you not understand, can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you use Government's site for filing of returns. Why? These websites cannot be held liable if they make any mistake in calculation or generation of XML file. With government site you are at least sure they will be correct.

Finally, its your choice.

Comment: Is ClearTax also one of those?